# What is the word for a piece of art depicting several people?

Tags: single-word-requests

It's like a portrait, but it's of several people, not just one. It's a still frame (as opposed to something like a video or movie), but a "still life" only depicts inanimate objects, so that term doesn't work, either.

Comment: I'm certainly no authority on art, but how about "a group study"?

Comment: A group portrait, if people are involved.

Answer (score 4):

Um... [group portrait](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/18566/what-is-the-definition-of-portrait-photography/18587#18587)?

> By the very existence of the term "group portrait", clearly such a thing exists. One can also say "individual portrait", but generally the implication of the term alone is that a single person is portrayed.